# Is there an official index of IE 11 patches and corresponding builds?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, patch

Our software lists IE 11 as supported software, but with the expectation that we only test against the latest available build of the product.

I cannot find anything from Microsoft that indexes the list of IE 11 patches and builds.

[This page from Microsoft indexes IE builds through v10.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/969393/information-about-internet-explorer-versions)

[This Wikipedia page includes some of the IE builds for IE 11.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11)

But I currently (04/21/2020) have a build not listed on the Wikipedia page (11.778.18362.0).
Yes I could edit it, but my goal is to be able to actually identify what the latest build for IE 11 is publicly available.

Does anyone know if a resource that indexes this?
Ideally Microsoft, as the vendor, would be indexing it, but I can't seem to see anything from them that shows they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know if a resource that indexes this?

No; Microsoft does not publish this information.  However, Microsoft does publish this information for `EdgeHTML` and `Chromium Edge`, through the use of Microsoft docs [EdgeHTML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide) and for [Chromium Edge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/whats-new/2019/12/devtools).

**Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10 will always share the same build as the version of Windows 10 it's running on.**  For instance, 11.1098.11763.0, only runs on `Windows 10 version 1809` (OS Build 17763.1098).

> Ideally Microsoft, as the vendor, would be indexing it, but I can't seem to see anything from them that shows they do.

Since Microsoft publishes the same security patches to IE11, to all supported versions of Windows 10, I would imagine they don't see the need to do this.  Since the version of IE11, will always correspond with the cumulative update installed on Windows 10, there isn't a need to document this information twice.

[Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 update history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464619)

Comment: Just checked my OS Version vs. IE version
OS Version 1909 Build 18363.778
IE 11.778.18362
Sure enough. I didn't realize that the 2 matched up like that. Knowing this, I agree, double documenting it is moot. 
I appreciate that insight, thanks!
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4549951
The Build of

Comment: @FuzzEvans - You also have to consider IE11 is most definitely a legacy browser.  Microsoft is keeping it secure likely for the duration of Windows 8.1 support.  Migration to TLS 1.3 will likely accelerate that timeline.  World events might delay those announcements by a few months.  I fully expect IE11 to not be supported at all by 2022.  Chromium Edge adoption by Enterprise might determine the exact timeline.